# fragmentation problem in decision tree

Tags: random-forest, cart, naive-bayes, natural-language

I am taking a `NLP` class, in which it says `decision tree` has the fragmentation problem.

It says `Naive Bayes` is :

> "Very good in domains with many equally important features.
>   `Decision Trees` suffer from fragmentation in such cases – especially if little data"

However, it doesn't explain about it further.

---

In my past opinion, `decision tree ensembles` should outperforms `Naive Bayes` in any cases since it hold no assumption about data. So I am curious about what it is, but *little* info I can find at Google.

Could you please explain fragmentation problem to me, thanks.

Comment: Note that decision tree and decision tree ensembles are two different worlds -- fragmentation (basically noise in the near-leaf branches) in ensemble should average out. Single decision tree is mostly about making interpretable and meaningful model, not necessarily perfectly accurate.